# Angular2 RC4: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotationCls' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts

I recently moved from angular beta 14 to using Angular2 RC4. I am attempting to use angular2-highcharts but get the error when setting the directive. I have tried using google charts and also experienced the exact same error:

**Angular2: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotationCls' of undefined**

Here is my chart component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
selector: 'bar-chart-demo',
templateUrl: 'app/components/dash-features/charts/my-chart.html'
directives: [ChartModule]
})

export class Charting {

constructor() {
    this.options = {
        title : { text : 'simple chart' },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        }]
    };
}
options: HighchartsOptions;
```

}

chart html:

```
 <chart [options]="options"></chart>
```

and system.config.js

```
(function(global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
'rxjs':                       '/node_modules/rxjs',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
'@angular':                   '/node_modules/@angular',
'highcharts/highstock.src': '/node_modules/highcharts/highstock.js',
'angular2-highcharts': '/node_modules/angular2-highcharts',


};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
'angular2-highcharts': { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
};

var packageNames = [
'@angular/common',
'@angular/compiler',
'@angular/core',
'@angular/http',
'@angular/platform-browser',
'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
'@angular/router',
'@angular/router-deprecated',
'@angular/testing',
'@angular/upgrade',
];

 // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': {      main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
map: map,
packages: packages
}

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);

})(this);
System.import('app/main')
.then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: Module aren't introduced until _after_ RC4. The library you are using is using a new Angular version. You might want to grab an earlier version that doesn't use modules, where you can just use its directives

Comment: Great, that worked